# Android's equivalent to IOS' networkActivityIndicatorVisible?

Tags: android, ios, android-notification-bar

How can I display a network indicator on Android's status bar? What is the equivalent of IOS' `networkActivityIndicatorVisible` in Android? Or if there's none, how can I create a similar network indicator in Android?